# How to speed up deletion of Worksheets in a large Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

Deleting sheets in large (>25 MB) Excel workbooks is quite slow (multiple seconds).

This is the case if I delete the sheets manually as well as via VBA.

I want to delete (~10) worksheets with previous results in a >25 MB Excel file via a VBA script.

How do I speed up the deletion of worksheets?

Running O365

I implemented the "usual" tricks to increase VBA speed

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

VBA code to delete sheets: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetProjectResults).Delete`

Comment: You might want to look into editing the underlying xml file yourself. There are libraries that can help you with that. Often this is much faster than using the API

Comment: Have you tried deleting the data from the worksheets first (`Worksheet.Rows.Delete` and/or `Worksheet.Columns.Delete`)?  Deleting 999 empty worksheets only takes about 9.7 seconds

Comment: Depending on the workbook specifics, it might be faster to turn the problem on its head. Instead of deleting what you don't need, maybe try copying out to a new workbook what you need to keep.